# HP 2114/15/16 floating point conversion

Tags: floating-point, converters, pascal

I have some files with floating point values in them that I'm having problems figuring out their exact encoding.  I've tried several ways to convert to a standard double value, but haven't had much luck.  I know what the values are supposed to convert to, but need a method to extract directly from the files.

These are HP-1000 (HP21xx) series floating point values.  Similar to 48 bit Pascal, but not the same.

Other than some old, unreliable documentation (couldn't get a conversion using what it claimed was the format), and a list of formats from quadibloc.com I have found nothing else.  Format from quadibloc gives the following:

```
(Note, big-endian order)

MSb: mantissa sign (says it's 2s complement)

39 bits: mantissa

7 bits: exponent

1 bit: exponent sign
```

The other documentation isn't clear, but seems to say it's all 2s complement.
I've tried the Pascal conversion code I found, but it doesn't even come close. (after moving the exponent sign to high bit of the byte).

Examples, converted using a PPC that emulates an HP-1000:

```
A7EB851EB90A    -22.02

A870A3D70A0A    -21.89

A8AE147AE20A    -21.83

A8E147AE140A    -21.78

A9666666670A    -21.65

AC70A3D70A0A    -20.89

ACC28F5C290A    -20.81

ACCCCCCCCC0A    -20.8

AE70A3D70B0A    -20.39

AEB851EB850A    -20.32
```

This was from only one file.  I have at least 100 of these files to extract from.

Any ideas?  Sure would be appreciated.

Edit: I guess I should have said what language I am working in.  In this case, it's C#.  As for additional data, I have a ton of it.  More examples here, these include negative exponents, at least when converted to decimal.

```
400000000002    1
43851EB85204    2.11
451EB851EB04    2.16
4C7AE147AE04    2.39
4EC4EC4EC5F3    4.8076923077E-03
519999999A04    2.55
5838B6BE9BF3    5.3846153846E-03
5B851EB85202    1.43
5BD70A3D7108    11.48
5C7AE147AE08    11.56
5E51EB851E08    11.79
5FD70A3D7108    11.98
62E147AE1508    12.36
64A3D70A3E08    12.58
666666666702    1.6
67AE147AE202    1.62
6B204B9E54F3    6.5384615385E-03
733333333302    1.8
762762762AF3    7.2115384616E-03
794DFB4619F3    7.4038461538E-03
7C74941627F3    7.5961538465E-03
7E07E07E14F3    7.6923076925E-03
```

Should have included positive numbers before.

Tried the suggestions, but in C#.  Wildly different results.  I even split out the bits of the calculations, but I get very high numbers compared to the numbers given in the suggestions.  Here's the code with the bits expanded.

```
    Int64[] test_data = new Int64[] {
        0xA7EB851EB90A, 0xA870A3D70A0A, 0xA8AE147AE20A, 0xA8E147AE140A,
        0xA9666666670A, 0xAC70A3D70A0A, 0xACC28F5C290A, 0xACCCCCCCCC0A,
        0xAE70A3D70B0A, 0xAEB851EB850A, 0x400000000002, 0x43851EB85204,
        0x451EB851EB04, 0x4C7AE147AE04, 0x4EC4EC4EC5F3, 0x519999999A04,
        0x5838B6BE9BF3, 0x5B851EB85202, 0x5BD70A3D7108, 0x5C7AE147AE08,
        0x5E51EB851E08, 0x5FD70A3D7108, 0x62E147AE1508, 0x64A3D70A3E08,
        0x666666666702, 0x67AE147AE202, 0x6B204B9E54F3, 0x733333333302,
        0x762762762AF3, 0x794DFB4619F3, 0x7C74941627F3, 0x7E07E07E14F3
    };

    private void Checkit()
    {
        Byte[] td = new Byte[6];                        // 6 byte array for reversed data
        Byte[] ld = new Byte[8];                        // 8 byte conversion array

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < test_data.Length; i++)    // Loop through data
        {
            ld = BitConverter.GetBytes(test_data[i]);   // Get value as byte array
            for (Int32 j = 0; j < 6; j++)               // Copy the bytes in reverse
                td[5 - j] = ld[j];
            // Go test them
            Console.WriteLine("{0:X6}  --> {1:E}", test_data[i], Real48ToDouble(ref td));
        }
    }

    Double Real48ToDouble(ref Byte[] realValue)
    {
        // Values are using input value of A7EB851EB90A and 7E07E07E14F3
        if (realValue[0] == 0)
            return 0.0;                                     // Null exponent = 0

        Byte[] b = new Byte[8] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // 64 bit byte array
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < 5; i++)                       // Copy over the 48 bit info
            b[4 - i] = realValue[i];

        Int64 mant = BitConverter.ToInt64(b, 0);            // 0x000000A7EB851EB9 - Get mantissa with sign
                                                            // 0x0000007E07E07E14
        Int32 expo = realValue[5];                          // 0x0000000A - Grab the exponent
                                                            // 0x000000F3
        Int32 mant_sign = (Int32)(mant >> 39);              // 0x00000001
                                                            // 0x00000000

        // sign extend mantissa from 40 to 64 bits, then take absolute value
        mant = (Int64)((mant ^ (1L << 39)) - (1L << 39));   // 0xFFFFFFA7EB851EB9 - First calc
                                                            // 0x0000007E07E07E14
        mant = Math.Abs(mant);                              // 0x00000058147AE147 - Make absolute
                                                            // 0x0000007E07E07E14

        // convert mantissa to floating-point
        Double fmant = mant * Math.Pow(2, -39.0);           // 0.68812499999876309 - Second calc
                                                            // 0.98461538463743636
        // rotate exponent field right by 1 bit
        expo = (expo >> 1) | ((expo & 1) << 7);             // 0x00000005
                                                            // 0x000000F9
        // sign extend exponent from 8 to 32 bits
        expo = ((expo ^ (1 << 7)) - (1 << 7));              // 0x00000005
                                                            // 0xFFFFFFF9

        // compute scale factor from exponent field
        Double scale = Math.Pow(2, expo);                   // 32.0 - Scale
                                                            // 0.0078125

        // scale mantissa, and apply sign bit for final result
        Double num = fmant * scale;                         // 22.019999999960419 - Make the final abs number
                                                            // 0.0076923076924799716

        return (mant_sign != 0) ? (-num) : num;             // -22.019999999960419 - Return with sign
                                                            // 0.0076923076924799716
    }
```

Changed code above
The code above is now working correctly.

Comment: From [Floating-Point Formats](http://www.oneonta.edu/faculty/zhangs/csci201/general%20Floating%20Point%20Format.htm): *A floating-point number began with a two's complement mantissa, and then ended with seven bits of exponent, followed by the sign of the exponent, neither of which was complemented when the number was negative. Floating-point numbers could occupy either two or three 16-bit words, depending on whether they were single or double precision.*

Comment: @Andy The leading seven bytes appear to be the two's complement mantissa. Look at -20.8, which after appropriate scaling converts to `ACCCC...` as a two's complement number. The problem I have is figuring out how the last byte `0A` maps to the exponent. Do you have additional example values from a different binade? That would presumably clarify the exponent encoding.

Comment: I meant "the leading *five* bytes" represent the two's complement mantissa. So the value is (`0xACCCCCCCCC` / 2^39) * 2^expo.

Comment: [This document](http://www.hpl.hp.com/hpjournal/pdfs/IssuePDFs/1978-10.pdf), p. 14 states: "All mantissas are  normalized, which means they are in the ranges [½, 1) and [-1, -½)". So the value of the mantissa is the signed 40-bit integer represented by the first five bytes divided by 2^40.

Comment: The LSB of the last byte is the sign bit of the exponent. So exponent byte `0A` corresponds to exponent of `0x0A`/2 = 10/2 = 5. Altogether: (0xacccccccc / 2^40) * 2^5 = -0.65 * 2^5 = -20.8. Sorry, I can't provide Pascal code, I am no longer fluent (it's been decades since I last used it). But I think the decoding is clear now.

Comment: @Andy I guess the scale factor is still an issue, I was off by one in the power of two in my last comment. E.g. `64A3D70A3E08`. Normalization criterion requires: mantissa is `0x64A3D70A3E` / 2^39 = 0.78625, exponent field 0x08 says scale factor is 2^(8/2) = 16, so value is 0.785625*16 = 12.58. E.g. previous example: `0xACCCCCCCCC` = - (`0x5333333333` / 2^39) = - (0.65). Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Andy Do you also have examples of numbers just smaller than 1? The encoding of negative exponents still seems mysterious, the examples with exponent field `F3` above all seem to have a true exponent of -7 (e.g. scale factor applied to mantissa is 2^-7), but I don't see how that jibes with an exponent field of `F3`. E.g. `0x7E07E07E14` / 2*^39 = 0.984615384637, 0.984615384637 * 2^-7 = 7.692307692480e-3

Comment: 47494160E2F7 .017403846154
4877BAAEE2F5 8.8461538463E-03
5838B6BEB1ED 6.7307692311E-04
61AC812E7AF5 .011923076923
6B204B9E55F5 .013076923077
7D70A3D70A00 .98
My brain was fried on the ^,  Something I should have noticed.  In skipping the XOR line and changing the power to -40, it was a LOT closer, but still off A7EB851EB90A became (-20.99 when it should be 22.02)  New code added above.

Comment: I don't see how any of them work with an F3 exponent.  Converts to 79 with the right shift by 1.  121 digits to the left doesn't sound right, but that's what the PPC emulating HP-1000 put out.  I got the binary by extracting them directly from the file, so those are definitely right.  Since I have no info on how the emulator was written, I can't say the same for the decimal numbers.  However this system has been in use quite some time, so I'd think data being off would have been noticed by now.

Comment: @Andy I think I figured out how the negative exponents work. First, *rotate* the exponent byte right by 1, then treat resulting number as an 8-bit, signed, two's-complement integer. Seems a bit weird, but works with all posted examples. I can only speculate that this arrangement was chosen so as to place the "sign bit" of the exponent in bit 0, which may have had architectural advantages. So `0xF3` turns into `0xF9` after the rotate, which is -7, so the scale factor is 2^{-7}. Your code above scales mantissa by 2^{-33} instead of 2^{-39}. See my latest code version in the answer for reference.

Comment: @Andy Your currently posted C# code is missing the exponent byte rotation followed by sign extension.

Comment: Changed code.  It's about as close to yours as C# allows.  Had to account for reversed bytes (Big endian) in the original values.  Some items are converted correctly, but others aren't.  Rather baffling to me.  I guess if I could see the intermediate values, it might give some clue.

Comment: @Andy If you could point to one particular input from among your posted test vectors that does not work with your C# code, I'd be happy to provide a step-by-step list of intermediate values in my posted code.

Comment: @Andy Here is a step-by-step list of variables for the first test vector: `test_data=0000a7eb851eb90a; mant=000000a7eb851eb9; expo=0000000a; mant_sign=00000001; mant=ffffffa7eb851eb9; mant=00000058147ae147; fmant= 6.8812499999876309e-001; expo=00000005; expo=00000005; scale= 3.2000000000000000e+001; num= 2.2019999999960419e+001; num=-2.2019999999960419e+001`. In your code, the sign-extension of `mant` doesn't seem to work correctly. Note that *all* operands *during* this computation must be 64-bit integers, your code seems to convert to 64-bit integer only *after* the computation is done.

Comment: @Andy: Try using `((Int64)1` << 39)` instead of `(1 << 39)`.

Comment: @Andy: According to [Microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx), this should also work: `(1L << 39)`, and is closest to my C code (where the `LL` suffix is used).

Comment: That fixed it.  (Int64) had no effect, but the L did.  No notice of a possible cast issue from the compiler, and usually it does give something.  You can see that in the final code (posted above) where I had some casts.  Thanks a lot for all the help you've given me on this one.  I was about pulling my hair out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An article in [Hewlett-Packard Journal, October 1978](http://www.hpl.hp.com/hpjournal/pdfs/IssuePDFs/1978-10.pdf), pg. 14 gives the following information about the floating-point format used here:

> Extended-precision numbers have a 39-bit signed mantissa and the same
>   seven-bit signed exponent. All mantissas are normalized, which means
>   they are in the ranges [½, 1) and [-1, -½).

Considered together with the information in the question this means the mantissa is a signed, two's-complement, 40-bit integer represented by the first five bytes, and must be divided by 2<sup>39</sup> to get its numerical floating-point value.

The binary exponent is stored in the last byte. Based on the description of the 40-bit mantissa field as a 39-bit mantissa in the journal article, while the exponent is described a having seven bits, together with information on the exponent sign bit from the question, it appears that the exponent is a signed, two's-complement 8-bit integer, which has been rotated left by one bit so that its sign bit winds up in bit [0] of the exponent byte. To process it, we need to rotate right one bit.

Based on the above information, I wrote the following C99 program that successfully decodes the test vectors from the question:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

int64_t test_data [] =
{
    0xA7EB851EB90A, 0xA870A3D70A0A, 0xA8AE147AE20A, 0xA8E147AE140A,
    0xA9666666670A, 0xAC70A3D70A0A, 0xACC28F5C290A, 0xACCCCCCCCC0A,
    0xAE70A3D70B0A, 0xAEB851EB850A, 0x400000000002, 0x43851EB85204,
    0x451EB851EB04, 0x4C7AE147AE04, 0x4EC4EC4EC5F3, 0x519999999A04,
    0x5838B6BE9BF3, 0x5B851EB85202, 0x5BD70A3D7108, 0x5C7AE147AE08,
    0x5E51EB851E08, 0x5FD70A3D7108, 0x62E147AE1508, 0x64A3D70A3E08,
    0x666666666702, 0x67AE147AE202, 0x6B204B9E54F3, 0x733333333302,
    0x762762762AF3, 0x794DFB4619F3, 0x7C74941627F3, 0x7E07E07E14F3
};
#define NBR_TEST_VECTORS (sizeof(test_data) / sizeof(int64_t))

int main (void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NBR_TEST_VECTORS; i++) {

        // extract mantissa and exponent bits
        int64_t mant = test_data[i] >> 8;
        int expo = test_data[i] & 0xFF;
        int mant_sign = mant >> 39;

        // sign extend mantissa from 40 to 64 bits, then take absolute value
        mant = ((mant ^ (1LL << 39)) - (1LL << 39));
        mant = llabs (mant);

        // convert mantissa to floating-point
        double fmant = mant * pow (2.0, -39.0);

        // rotate exponent field right by 1 bit
        expo = (expo >> 1) | ((expo & 1) << 7);

        // sign extend exponent from 8 to 32 bits
        expo = ((expo ^ (1 << 7)) - (1 << 7));

        // compute scale factor from exponent field
        double scale = pow (2.0, expo);

        // scale mantissa, and apply sign bit for final result
        double num = fmant * scale;
        num = mant_sign ? -num : num;

        printf ("%012llx  --> % 20.11e\n", test_data[i], num);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output of the above program should look as follows:

```
a7eb851eb90a  -->  -2.20200000000e+001
a870a3d70a0a  -->  -2.18900000000e+001
a8ae147ae20a  -->  -2.18300000000e+001
a8e147ae140a  -->  -2.17800000000e+001
a9666666670a  -->  -2.16500000000e+001
ac70a3d70a0a  -->  -2.08900000000e+001
acc28f5c290a  -->  -2.08100000000e+001
accccccccc0a  -->  -2.08000000000e+001
ae70a3d70b0a  -->  -2.03900000000e+001
aeb851eb850a  -->  -2.03200000000e+001
400000000002  -->   1.00000000000e+000
43851eb85204  -->   2.11000000000e+000
451eb851eb04  -->   2.16000000000e+000
4c7ae147ae04  -->   2.39000000000e+000
4ec4ec4ec5f3  -->   4.80769230769e-003
519999999a04  -->   2.55000000000e+000
5838b6be9bf3  -->   5.38461538456e-003
5b851eb85202  -->   1.43000000000e+000
5bd70a3d7108  -->   1.14800000000e+001
5c7ae147ae08  -->   1.15600000000e+001
5e51eb851e08  -->   1.17900000000e+001
5fd70a3d7108  -->   1.19800000000e+001
62e147ae1508  -->   1.23600000000e+001
64a3d70a3e08  -->   1.25800000000e+001
666666666702  -->   1.60000000000e+000
67ae147ae202  -->   1.62000000000e+000
6b204b9e54f3  -->   6.53846153847e-003
733333333302  -->   1.80000000000e+000
762762762af3  -->   7.21153846158e-003
794dfb4619f3  -->   7.40384615382e-003
7c74941627f3  -->   7.59615384651e-003
7e07e07e14f3  -->   7.69230769248e-003
```

Comment: Tried the above.  Using c#, the absolute value function is Math.Abs(value).  This throws an exception. The previous line is mant = (Int64)(Math.Pow(mant, (1 << 39)) - (1 << 39));  This results in 0x8000 000000000000 which represents -0.  I guess Pow doesn't like that.  Don't have exp2 or llabs in c#.  Either things aren't handled the same between C99 and C# or my brain is fried as I see nothing really different.

Comment: @Andy Sorry, I don't know C# at all. Note that `^` is the XOR operator in C (and C++) *not* exponentation! `llabs` is an absolute value function for 64-bit integers. Note the use of `1LL << 39`, the `LL` marks the `1` as a 64-bit value. I think `exp2(x)` could be `Math.Pow(2.0,x) ` in C#.

Comment: @Andy [Microsoft C# documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) tells me that C# also uses `^` as the bitwise XOR operator, just like C and C++. So I think you can copy that more or ess verbatim. In my code, I changed the calls to `exp2` to calls to `pow` which may make direct translation to C# easier.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of **njuffa** approach in Delphi

```
type
  THexabyte = array[0..5] of Byte;

function ConvertHPToDouble(const Data: THexabyte): Double;
var
  iexp: Integer;
  pbi: PByteArray;
  i64: Int64;
begin
  iexp := Data[5] shr 1;  //unsigned shift
  if (Data[5] and 1) <> 0 then    //use exp sign
     iexp := - iexp;
  pbi := @i64;
  pbi[0] := 0;
  pbi[1] := 0;
  pbi[2] := 0;
  pbi[3] := Data[4];    //shuffle bytes into intel order
  pbi[4] := Data[3];
  pbi[5] := Data[2];
  pbi[6] := Data[1];
  pbi[7] := Data[0];
  i64 := i64 div (1 shl 23);  //arithmetic shift saves sign
  Result := i64 / (Int64(1) shl (40 - iexp));
end;


var
  Data: THexabyte;
  i: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'A870A3D70A0A';
  for i := 0 to 5 do
    Data[i] := StrToInt('$' + Copy(s, i * 2 + 1, 2));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%14.7f', [ConvertHPToDouble(Data)]));
  // gives    -21.8900000
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting `njuffa's` code into Delphi:

> - The mantissa is left-shifted 16 bits to form a 64 bit signed integer.
> - The exponent is extracted and rotated right 1 bit to form a signed 8 bit integer.
> - The resulting double is scaled by multiplying the mantissa with `IntPower(2,-63+Exponent)`

---

```
program HP_Float_To_Double;    
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}    
uses
  System.SysUtils,Math;    
var
  test_data : TArray<Int64> = [
      $A7EB851EB90A, $A870A3D70A0A, $A8AE147AE20A, $A8E147AE140A,
      $A9666666670A, $AC70A3D70A0A, $ACC28F5C290A, $ACCCCCCCCC0A,
      $AE70A3D70B0A, $AEB851EB850A, $400000000002, $43851EB85204,
      $451EB851EB04, $4C7AE147AE04, $4EC4EC4EC5F3, $519999999A04,
      $5838B6BE9BF3, $5B851EB85202, $5BD70A3D7108, $5C7AE147AE08,
      $5E51EB851E08, $5FD70A3D7108, $62E147AE1508, $64A3D70A3E08,
      $666666666702, $67AE147AE202, $6B204B9E54F3, $733333333302,
      $762762762AF3, $794DFB4619F3, $7C74941627F3, $7E07E07E14F3];

function Exponent( b: Byte): ShortInt;
begin
  Result := (b shr 1) or ((b and 1) shl 7);
end;

function HPFloatToDouble( HP: Int64): Double;
var
  Exp: ShortInt;
begin
  HP := HP shl 16; // Shift left 16 bits
  Exp := Exponent(PByte(@HP)[2]); // Rotate exponent right 1 position into signed 8 bit
  HP := (HP and $FFFFFFFFFF000000); // Clear exponent part from mantissa
  Result := HP*IntPower(2,-63+Exp); // Scale result
end;

var
  I64 : Int64;
begin
  for I64 in test_data do
    WriteLn(Format('%x -> %20.11e',[I64, HPFloatToDouble(I64)]));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

The output is following:

```
A7EB851EB90A ->   -2,2020000000E+001
A870A3D70A0A ->   -2,1890000000E+001
A8AE147AE20A ->   -2,1830000000E+001
A8E147AE140A ->   -2,1780000000E+001
A9666666670A ->   -2,1650000000E+001
AC70A3D70A0A ->   -2,0890000000E+001
ACC28F5C290A ->   -2,0810000000E+001
ACCCCCCCCC0A ->   -2,0800000000E+001
AE70A3D70B0A ->   -2,0390000000E+001
AEB851EB850A ->   -2,0320000000E+001
400000000002 ->    1,0000000000E+000
43851EB85204 ->    2,1100000000E+000
451EB851EB04 ->    2,1600000000E+000
4C7AE147AE04 ->    2,3900000000E+000
4EC4EC4EC5F3 ->    4,8076923077E-003
519999999A04 ->    2,5500000000E+000
5838B6BE9BF3 ->    5,3846153846E-003
5B851EB85202 ->    1,4300000000E+000
5BD70A3D7108 ->    1,1480000000E+001
5C7AE147AE08 ->    1,1560000000E+001
5E51EB851E08 ->    1,1790000000E+001
5FD70A3D7108 ->    1,1980000000E+001
62E147AE1508 ->    1,2360000000E+001
64A3D70A3E08 ->    1,2580000000E+001
666666666702 ->    1,6000000000E+000
67AE147AE202 ->    1,6200000000E+000
6B204B9E54F3 ->    6,5384615385E-003
733333333302 ->    1,8000000000E+000
762762762AF3 ->    7,2115384616E-003
794DFB4619F3 ->    7,4038461538E-003
7C74941627F3 ->    7,5961538465E-003
7E07E07E14F3 ->    7,6923076925E-003
```