# Can a floating Point System with 2's or 1's Complements Mantissa be Normalized?

Tags: floating-point, twos-complement, ones-complement

As I understand a normalized mantissa is a fractional mantissa in which it's more significant bit, the one that equals 1/2, is always 1. And this is done in order to avoid repeated representations of the same number on the system.

But what happens if the Mantissa uses a 2's Complement or 1's Complement system. In that case, if the number is negative forcing that bit to 1 would cause that bit to have a null-value making it to not fulfill its purpose.
The other solution would be to force it to be a 0 in the case the number is negative but I imagine a physical implementation of that could get complicated.
And that makes me think, does a system with a normalized 2's or 1's complement mantissa even exist? And if they exist how do they work?

Comment: A normalized floating-point format does *not* imply the use of an implicit (hidden) most significant mantissa bit. For example, the 80-bit extended precision format of x87 FPUs is normalized, but uses an explicit integer bit. It uses sign-magnitude representation. For a floating-point number system utilizing normalized mantissas in two's complement representation, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174389/hp-2114-15-16-floating-point-conversion) and my answer.

Comment: think of this way normalized means x.y to some power where the power is within spec for the format (not denormal) and x is the fixed value for the format (usually a 1 or 2)  and y is then the mantissa once in that normalized format.  it just means you have shifted and adjusted the exponent as you go to the x.y format

Answer (score 0):

> Can a floating Point System with 2's or 1's Complements Mantissa be Normalized?

Yes - all sort of encodings are possible.  Many floating-point encodings have been tried - maybe even ones with a 2's or 1's Complements mantissa.  Yet the floating point formats that are most popular contain a sign, a sign-less *significand*, and exponent.

---

To clear up some (mis-)understandings:

> a normalized mantissa is a fractional mantissa in which it's more significant bit, the one that equals 1/2, is always 1

Note: better to use *significand/significant* than *mantissa*.

Floating point formats like [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) make a distinction between the the value of the signifcand and it encoding.

The value of significand `m` is 53 bits - usually thought of as a binary number as B.bbb...bbb.  The lower 52 are directly encoded.  The most significant one `B` is derived.  When the biased exponent is not 0, the most significant bit is 1 (*normal* numbers).  Else it is 0 (*sub-normal* numbers).

The most significant bit of the value is not always 1.   The most significant bit of the encoded 52 bits value is not always 1 either.

As *normal* numbers always have a most significant bit of 1, that bit is not encoded.  It is usually thought of as having a value of 1 and not 1/2.  1/2 could be used though and then lots of other constants describing the format would need to be adjusted too.

> And this is done in order to avoid repeated representations of the same number on the system.

Yes - but indirectly. A goal of a good floating point format is to encoded many different values with minimal space.  Any repeated representations would reduce that efficiency.  No or few repeated representations is a *result* of space efficiency goal.

> But what happens if the Mantissa uses a 2's Complement or 1's Complement system. In that case, if the number is negative forcing that bit to 1 would cause that bit to have a null-value making it to not fulfill its purpose.

This is curious as the "mantissa", signicand is sign-less.  Yet lets us combine the sign bit and signicand together as the sign-magnitude "mantissa" as is `sB.bbb...bbb`.   Changing this to some sort of 54-bit 2's complement implies that the derived `B` is 1 for positive numbers and 0 for negative ones.  Yes, forcing `B` to 1 is a bad design choice and neither it is required.

> The other solution would be to force it to be a 0 in the case the number is negative but I imagine a physical implementation of that could get complicated.

Yes it would be 0 in the case of negative numbers for *normal* numbers.   There is no overly complicated  issues preventing a physical implementation - quite trivial really.  Yet there is no demonstrated value for this alternative approach.  If you had a stack of money to implement the next processor with great floating point ability - would you bet on the common sign-magnitude floating point formats or attempt a 2's complement one?

> ... does a system with a normalized 2's or 1's complement mantissa even exist?

As memory serves, this was implemented.  Yet for [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect)  or major reasons, common floating point formats today do not use a 2's complement significand.  Darwinian technology pressure resulted in sign-magnitude floating point dominating the industry.  The key events lead up to  the issue of [IEEE 754-1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#History).  This detailed the many corners of floating point - yet also was written to reflect the leading hardware manufactures goals at the time.  2's or 1's complement mantissa along with many other floating point formats [missed the boat](https://tanyaboydassociates.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/missed-the-boat-270x300.jpg).